# How to visual select everything within a pair of fold markers

Tags: visual-mode, folding, visual-block

Are there simple tweaks that I can visual select everything with in a pair of fold markers? Just like what `vi"` will do for a pair of double quotes. Preferably `vi` plus some other keys.

Comment: Not the neatest but `zc` to close the fold then `yy` will yank the fold contents. If your foldmethod is marker it will select the markers as well

Comment: There is an example for a fold text object in the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a "text-object" in Vim terminology and you can find the list of these text-objects at [`:h text-objects`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#text-objects). As you can see there is not a built-in text-object for the folds.

However you might be interested in this plugin: [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user). It allows you to define your own text-objects easily.

Note that if you don't want to use a plugin you can simply use an operator pending mode mapping (see [`:h omap-info`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#omap-info)).

Comment: You will find in the wiki of vim-textobj-user the plugin [vim-textobj-fold](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-fold) which defines `iz` and `az` for you. However, I would have expected that `iz` does not select the fold markers. But it does. The difference is described in the docs. Luckily, there is a pull request and a fork which modify `iz` to ignore fold marker lines: [kana/vim-textobj-fold/pull/8](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-fold/pull/8) and [somini/vim-textobj-fold](https://github.com/somini/vim-textobj-fold)